# Can InfluxDb be configured for usage as an in memory database?

Tags: java, time-series, influxdb, in-memory-database

I have just started using the InfluxDb java client for storing some time series IoT data. I got around to thinking about performance and am curious to know if it is possible for us to use influx as an in memory database similar to H2 or sqlLite? Have not found any examples or information regarding this and would love some tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the only way to accomplish this would be to create a RAM-disk (file system in memory). Not very efficient: It will use an excessive amount of memory compared to a natively in-memory time-series database, and performance will not be as good as native due to the overhead imposed by the file system.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you need the performance? During write, or read? Influx already uses a lot in-memory techniques out of the box. In my opintion during write it should be no issue, if your are writing asynchronous to the database.

Otherwise you may need some kind of state service in between, to not have the whole database in memeroy be cached.